# Do we use plural of percent when having two percentages?

Tags: grammatical-number

Should I use percent or percents here?

"They are reported to be 7 and 8 **percent** respectively."

Regards.

Comment: This is more a matter of style than grammar.  Arguably you could use either.

Comment: @DavidM - Wrong!  There are two *percentages*, but there is only one *per 100* constant value.

Comment: As a general rule, we use a plural verb with two or more subjects when they are connected by 'and.'
Example: "A car and a bike are my means of transportation." On the same lines, "They are reported to be 7 and 8 percents respectively." I agree, though, that the presence of 'respectively' creates some amount of confusion.

Comment: //They are reported to be 7 and 8 percent respectively.// Can't it be better this way: a) They are reported to be 7% and 8%; b) They are reported to be 7 percent and 8 percent. c) They are reported to be 7 and 8 percents. "Respectively" should be used when two things should be related to two other things for which 'They' is not enough.

Answer (score 1):

No. *Seven and eight percent respectively* is a perfectly normal way to compare percentages. Here's another example (that I've just made up):

> The quantity of lead in municipal drinking water was measured in Paris and Rome. The concentrations were found to be 3 and 5 parts per billion, respectively.

Percent can be alternately written as *[parts] per hundred*. One would not write *parts per billions* as it does not make sense (how many billions?), nor would one write *parts per hundreds*.